# SQL Count uses info from join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to count the amount of times InternalMenuLinkItemNumber appears per sitenumber and per order mode. Then i need to show MenuItemID and i do that with a inner join using item numbers, but when i add this join it skews the QTY result. I've tried using distinct in the COUNT but then all the QTY is 1. Please assist.

Query and result where QTY result is 100% correct but no MenuItemID.

```
 SELECT ST_Sites.BusinessUnit,[ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber,InternalMenuLinkItemNumber,[ST_SalesMix].MenuItemID,OrderMode,SellingPrice,COUNT(ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.InternalMenuLinkItemNumber) as QTY 

FROM ST_AlohaSalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed

inner join ST_Sites on ST_Sites.SiteNumber= [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber 

where [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].BusinessDate between'2017-06-27'and'2017-07-03' and [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber = '1001006'

group by InternalMenuLinkItemNumber,[ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber,OrderMode,SellingPrice,ST_Sites.BusinessUnit,[ST_SalesMix].MenuItemID

order by InternalMenuLinkItemNumber
```

Result where QTY comes out as expected:

[image]

If I add the inner join to get MenuItemID:
Query:

```
SELECT ST_Sites.BusinessUnit,[ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber,InternalMenuLinkItemNumber,[ST_SalesMix].MenuItemID,OrderMode,SellingPrice,COUNT(ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.InternalMenuLinkItemNumber) as QTY 

FROM ST_AlohaSalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed

inner join ST_SalesMix on [ST_AlohaSalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].InternalMenuLinkItemNumber= ST_SalesMix.ItemNumber

inner join ST_Sites on ST_Sites.SiteNumber= [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber 

where [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].BusinessDate between'2017-06-27'and'2017-07-03' and [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber = '1001006'

group by InternalMenuLinkItemNumber,[ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber,OrderMode,SellingPrice,ST_Sites.BusinessUnit,[ST_SalesMix].MenuItemID

order by InternalMenuLinkItemNumber
```

Result where QTY is now way off:
[image]

If I use distinct:
Query:

```
SELECT ST_Sites.BusinessUnit,[ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber,InternalMenuLinkItemNumber,[ST_SalesMix].MenuItemID,OrderMode,SellingPrice,COUNT(distinct ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.InternalMenuLinkItemNumber) as QTY 

FROM ST_AlohaSalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed

inner join ST_SalesMix on [ST_AlohaSalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].InternalMenuLinkItemNumber= ST_SalesMix.ItemNumber

inner join ST_Sites on ST_Sites.SiteNumber= [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber 

where [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].BusinessDate between'2017-06-27'and'2017-07-03' and [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber = '1001006'

group by InternalMenuLinkItemNumber,[ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber,OrderMode,SellingPrice,ST_Sites.BusinessUnit,[ST_SalesMix].MenuItemID

order by InternalMenuLinkItemNumber
```

Result for QTY is now all 1:
[image]

Comment: What are the PKs and FKs of those tables?

Comment: Are you really using MySQL? (Looks more like SQL Server.)

Comment: You need to do the counting first in a subquery, then join the menu items afterwards or you need to do count(distinct ...), it's a bit hard to tell without sample data.

Comment: Why the MySQL tag??

Comment: Removed the ambiguous mysql product tag.

Comment: SQL-Server yes.

Comment: NameofConstraint: PK_ST_SalesMix SchemaName: dbo   TableName: ST_SalesMix ConstraintType: PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT

Comment: NameofConstraint: PK_ST_Sites SchemaName: dbo  TableName: ST_Sites  ConstraintType: PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT

Comment: @Deon Learn to use alias.  The very long table name is very annoying to read.

Comment: I just added a solution for you. It keeps your working query and joins to ST_SalesMix after the fact. Take a look; I think it should work - and don't forget to 'Accept' my answer if it helps you.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the solutions that have been provided for you?

Comment: Sorry I just saw your message - my screen hadn't updated since I got home.  Would you mind 'Accepting' that as the answer then.  Thanks, John.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like

```
SELECT SiteNumber, OrderMode, count([DISTINCT?] InternalMenuLinkItemNumber)
...
GROUP BY SiteNumber, OrderMode
```

You want to count the InternalMenuLinkItemNumber, so InternalMenuLinkItemNumber must not occur in the `GROUP BY` clause.

**EDIT:**
When using GROUP BY, the SELECT list may only contain columns also mentioned in the GROUP BY clause, or aggregate functions (on arbitrary columns).

Comment: if I remove it from group by then it complains "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Column 'ST_AlohaSalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.InternalMenuLinkItemNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: And if I write [DISTINCT?] I get error: "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'ST_AlohaSalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed'."

Comment: With `[DISTINCT?]`, I meant depending on your use case you might need ?
`DISTINCT` here.

Comment: with distinct it makes the result of the count 1 for everything

Comment: That's because you're GROUPing BY InternalMenuLinkItemNumber.

Comment: but if i remove InternalMenuLinkItemNumber from the grouping I get ""Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 Column 'ST_AlohaSalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.InternalMenuLinkItemNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: And if i remove it from the select (not the count part) then the query completes but count result is very wrong.

Comment: Sorry for my first, wrong edit of my answer. Corrected it. - Remove InternalMenuLinkItemNumber from the select and from the group by clause. Think about it: If you want to count InternalMenuLinkItemNumber, you can neither group by it, nor select a distinct column value...

Comment: I just added a solution for you.  It keeps your working query and joins to ST_SalesMix after the fact.  I think it should work.

Comment: Sorry fjf2000, I meant to comment on his question not your answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

```
SELECT a.InternalMenuLinkItemNumber, a.SiteNumber, a.OrderMode, a.SellingPrice, a.BusinessUnit, a.MenuItemID, a.QTY, CASE WHEN MAX(b.MenuItemID) = MIN(b.MenuItemID) THEN MAX(b.MenuItemID) ELSE -1 END AS MenuItemID
    FROM
        (SELECT ST_Sites.BusinessUnit, [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber, InternalMenuLinkItemNumber, [ST_SalesMix].MenuItemID, OrderMode, SellingPrice, COUNT(ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed.InternalMenuLinkItemNumber) as QTY 
            FROM ST_AlohaSalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed
            INNER JOIN ST_Sites on ST_Sites.SiteNumber = [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber 
            WHERE [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].BusinessDate between'2017-06-27'and'2017-07-03' and [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber = '1001006'
            GROUP BY InternalMenuLinkItemNumber, [ST_SalesMixTransactions_RealTimeFeed].SiteNumber, OrderMode, SellingPrice, ST_Sites.BusinessUnit, [ST_SalesMix].MenuItemID
         ) a
    INNER JOIN ST_SalesMix b ON a.InternalMenuLinkItemNumber = b.ItemNumber
    GROUP BY a.InternalMenuLinkItemNumber, a.SiteNumber, a.OrderMode, a.SellingPrice, a.BusinessUnit, a.MenuItemID, a.QTY
    ORDER BY a.InternalMenuLinkItemNumber
```

It works on the theory that your first query gives good counts, so keep that as it is (it's now the inner query) and then do the problematic join outside of it.  Obviously there are many rows from ST_SalesMix for each properly counted row in the first query, so I'm grouping on the original group list but that means that you might get multiple MenuItemIDs.  I'm checking for that in the CASE statement by testing the MAX and MIN MenuItemIDs - if they are the same return MAX(MenuItemID) otherwise I'm returning -1 as an error flag to indicate that there were multiple MenuItemIDs associated with this group.  It might not be the most efficient method but I didn't have much to go on.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

all is sorted now. Thanks to everyone.
@jwolf your suggested query was the answer.

Comment: Sorry I just saw this message - my screen hadn't updated yet.  Would you mind 'Accepting' that as the answer then.  Thanks, John.

Comment: Hi Deon, I'm glad my solution worked for you.  Would you mind 'Accepting' it as the answer. Thanks, John.